# using apply to append text with messy results

Tags: r

I would like move across columns and append text based on the value in the cell of a data table.

Here's the current table:

```
table = data.frame(
    c1 = c("Under","Over"), 
    c2 = c("Under", "Over") , 
    c3 = c("NA","Under"))  
apply(  table[, 1:3],  2,  function(x)  {
   if(x=="Under"){
       paste0("\\cellcolor{", x, "}")
    }else{ 
       paste0("\\cellcolor333{", x, "}")
   }
 })
```

right now this is not working because in column 3 for Under there should not be

```
\\cellcolor333 it should just be \\cellcolor
```

What the correct way?

Comment: Your problem is that you're using `if (x == 'Under')` on a vector with `length(x) > 1`, so only the first element of the column is being used. Does the first element of `c3` equal `"Under"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use vectorized functions that operate over the whole vector at once. `if` does not do this, but `ifelse()` does. Try

```
as.data.frame(lapply(table[, 1:3], function(x)  {
       paste0("\\cellcolor", ifelse(x=="Under","","333"), "{", x, "}")
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

The following code anwers your question:

```
apply(table,  2,  function(x)  ifelse(x=="Under",paste0("\\cellcolor{", x, "}"),paste0("\\cellcolor333{", x, "}")))
     c1                     c2                     c3                  
[1,] "\\cellcolor{Under}"   "\\cellcolor{Under}"   "\\cellcolor333{NA}"
[2,] "\\cellcolor333{Over}" "\\cellcolor333{Over}" "\\cellcolor{Under}"
```

### Explanation

`table` is the same as `table[,1:3]`. The second argument of `apply` is 2, so `x` in the function is each column of your table,i.e. a vector of two elements, **if** doesn't take a vector as a condition nor it returns a vector as a result, so you need to use **ifelse()** function instead.